# Integration Testing or Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to Unit Test a login and I'm wondering if testing the login stage would be Unit Testing or Integration Testing?

I've searched to see if there is an example or to see if it is explained but I'm unable to find an answer.

The login stage is just a simple Email and Password to log in with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a single login component would be a unit test.  Access to any directory or data store should be mocked.

If your test includes a page, a database or directory, or anything else than a single component it's an integration test.

Comment: The way I see it is that a unit test can contain smaller units in it. It's only when you cross the boundaries to an external system (datetime, filesystem, database, etc) that we speak of an integration test.